# Find next leap year from today's date in c#

Tags: c#

I want to find the next leap year from today's date.

For ex.,

```
Date        NextLeapDate
-----       ------------
2016-01-01   2016-02-29
2016-05-24   2020-02-29
2017-02-03   2020-02-29
```

This is what I have so far to get the next leap year but it's getting me wrong value,

```
public int GetNextLeapYear(int year)
{
    bool isLeapYear = false;

    while (true)
    {
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
        {
            isLeapYear = true;
        }
        else
        {
            year = year + 1;
            GetNextLeapYear(year);
        }
        break;
    }
    return year;
}
```

Comment: put the break in first if statement, or simply just return year, oops jus saw recursion, hard to read, jus remove that call

Comment: You may wish to prepend the system call with a return (return what the inner call returns instead of just some random year)

Comment: Also don't call the function again - there's no need to call `GetNextLeapYear` in the else block.  Use a loop or recursion, not both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DateTime GetNextLeapDate (DateTime baseDate)
{
    int year = baseDate.Year;

    // start in the next year if we’re already in March
    if (baseDate.Month > 2)
        year++;

    // find next leap year
    while (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
        year++;

    // get last of February
    return new DateTime(year, 2, 29);
}
```

Note that we need to skip checking the current year if (and only if) the base date is already ahead of March (i.e. a possible leap day is already over). That way, we don’t get a result of February 29th, 2016 for e.g. today (time of this post).

Used like this, it returns the desired dates:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetNextLeapDate(new DateTime(2016, 01, 01))); // 2016-02-29
Console.WriteLine(GetNextLeapDate(new DateTime(2016, 05, 24))); // 2020-02-29
Console.WriteLine(GetNextLeapDate(new DateTime(2017, 02, 03))); // 2020-02-29
```

Comment: I like that you checked for the current year.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is only a part of the program? The below code is copied from the question and changed with my suggestion edit (as well as other simplifications) to make it work correctly.

```cs
public int GetNextLeapYear(int year)
{
    if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
    {
        return year;
    }
    else
    {
        year = year + 1;
        return GetNextLeapYear(year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need recursion. Try this:

```
public int GetNextLeapYear(int year)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
        {
            return year;
        }
        year = year + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use recursion to find the next leap year, you can change your method like so.

```
public int GetNextLeapYear(int year)
{
    if (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
    {
        return GetNextLeapYear(year + 1);
    }
    return year;
}
```

Using recursion, you don't need the While loop, you just need to check to see if you need to continue or return the value.  This also allows you to get rid of variables that are not needed.  @poke answer is more complete counting for the actual month that you are in and such.  I only answered this way to keep with using recursion like you had done.

Comment: using return instead of assigning to `year` allows tail recursion. Always try to do tail recursion when you can.

Comment: I believe that change would fix that issue.

Comment: It's good enough now (to optimize, you could strip the "year = year+1" line and instead give "year+1" as argument for the recursive call)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I had never heard of tail recursion before.  It's always fun to learn something new on items like this.

Comment: Tail recursion is not guaranteed to optimize, but it's a good way to help. It's something functional programming requires to prevent stack overflow, and other languages that can do recursion may also perform the same optimization (namely, tail call elimination or something like that) to actually avoid the cost of recursing in itself.